# React ref.current inside loop working only on first iteration

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have page where files with check boxes for labels are rendered from map. Basically user is then able to select/deselect files. 
Problem is I wanted to add feature that you can select/deselect all files with on button click.
I tried to use refs for that.

```
 const fileRef = React.useRef([]);
```

Then I have simple map:

```
files.map((file, index) => 
    <FormControlLabel 
        ref={el => fileRef.current[index] = el}
        control={...}
        label={file.name}
    />
)
```

And I tried to create function like that:

```
const selectAll = () => {
    for(let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        fileRef.current[i].control.click();
    }
}
```

Problem is only first file is selected/deselected. Selected files are hold in array. Manual click is handled with simple handleChange where I select checkbox with event.target.value and when deselecting I just use array.filter.

If I for example make two buttons with two different indexes, then it works but inside the loop the index seems not to take effect.

Is there way to select/deselect all files with only one click? I assume deselecting is easy, I just clear array but selecting seems to be problem. Ref only works with first item.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a ref to try and click all the checkboxes, just change your file state to have all the files checked.

I'll assume that `files` is loaded in by some api call and your component is doing something like

```
const [files, setFiles] = useState([])

useEffect(() => {
  loadFiles().then(files => {
    const filesWithCheckParam = files.map(file => ({ ...file, isChecked: false }))
    setFiles(filesWithCheckParam)
  })
}, [])
```

Now you can put in a button or another checkbox or whatever with a click handler that changes the file state like

```
const handleCheckAllClick = checked => {
  setFiles(fs => fs.map(f => ({ ...f, isChecked: checked })))
}
```

Comment: Actually files are loaded from props and doesn't have field isChecked. This is also the main problem why I even thought about using refs. Checked/unchecked is determined with function that checks if file is in selected array and returns boolean that is used inside mui Checkbox component

Comment: it's fine if it comes from props, just forget about the useEffect and put the files prop straight into the state. 

Reading the value of a checkbox with a ref is simply not the react way.